# Product for block-encoding of two density operators

Tags: quantum-algorithms, linear-algebra

I know for density operator like $\rho$, we have a block-encoding matrix with purification operator and SWAP gate: $BE_{\rho} = \begin{bmatrix} \rho & \cdot \\ \cdot & \cdot \end{bmatrix}$. But in this case, I feel unable to guarantee that the product of $U_\rho$ and $U_\sigma$ is still a block-encoding matrix of $\rho\sigma$, even allowing for some error. This is because I don’t know the other blocks of the block-encoding matrix $U_\rho$ and $U_\sigma$. Although Lemma 54 in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.01838) provides a proof, I am still very confused. Could you give some examples to illustrate the specific form of the product of block-encoding matrices?